# How to insert symbol in an UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working with a UITextView. I want to insert special symbols e.g. at the beginning of the actual line of text. And now I think about two possibilities. First is 
to add some letters to the font. So I have every time the right Size of the symbol. Second is the way to insert an image at the beginning of the line. The problem could be to change the size fo the image when the font size changes. What is the best way and how can I do this. I already work with NSAttributedString.

Many thanks
Jens